# Resize and Drag an Element using jsPlumb

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, draggable, jsplumb

I am working with the jsPlumb library to implement a simple interface where an element can be dragged from the toolbox and dropped onto the container. Here, I have an element('partitiondrop') that needs to be re-sizable and draggable at the same time. But, the following code doesn't permit the partition to be resized. Without the `jsPlumb.draggable`, the resize function works but once the element is dropped it can't be dragged.

```
drop: function (e, ui) {
    var dropElem = ui.draggable.attr('class');
    droppedElement = ui.helper.clone();
    ui.helper.remove();
    $(droppedElement).removeAttr("class");
    $(droppedElement).draggable({containment: "container"});
    jsPlumb.repaint(ui.helper);

    var newAgent = $('<div>').attr('id', i).addClass('partitiondrop');
    $(droppedElement).draggable({containment: "container"});

    newAgent.css({
        'top': e.pageY,
         'left': e.pageX
    });

    $('#container').append(newAgent);

    jsPlumb.draggable(newAgent, {
         containment: 'parent'     
    });

    $(newAgent).resizable({
         resize : function(event, ui) {
         jsPlumb.repaint(ui.helper);
         }
    });
}
```

**CSS for partitiondrop**

```
.partitiondrop {
    border: 1px solid #346789;
    resize: both;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    ...
    z-index: 20;
    position: absolute;
    ...
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Suggestions in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [interact.js](http://interactjs.io/) Javascript library for this. It provides an extensive function library specially methods to perform resizing and dragging at the same time.

```
interact('.resize-drag')
  .draggable({
    onmove: window.dragMoveListener
  })
  .resizable({
    preserveAspectRatio: true,
    edges: { left: true, right: true, bottom: true, top: true }
  })
  .on('resizemove', function (event) {
    var target = event.target,
        x = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-x')) || 0),
        y = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-y')) || 0);
// update the element's style
target.style.width  = event.rect.width + 'px';
target.style.height = event.rect.height + 'px';

// translate when resizing from top or left edges
x += event.deltaRect.left;
y += event.deltaRect.top;

target.style.webkitTransform = target.style.transform =
    'translate(' + x + 'px,' + y + 'px)';

target.setAttribute('data-x', x);
target.setAttribute('data-y', y);
target.textContent = Math.round(event.rect.width) + '×' + Math.round(event.rect.height);
});
```